# Forward declare a template class that needs to return to the original class?

Tags: c++

How would I untangle this knot? I'm using Visual Studio as my compiler, if it matters. Obviously one could just move MOO to otherClass and move otherclass up, but this is a model for a more complex problem that's happening in reality. I think a forward definition is needed here, but I'm not sure how to structure it.

Can this knot even be untangled, or do I have to break sampClass into two classes, or a class with an interface?

```
#include <iostream>
class sampClass
{
public:
    template <typename Z>
    otherClass<Z> potato()
    {
        return otherClass<Z>(this);

    }
    sampClass(int a)
    {
        m_a = a;
    }
    void moo()
    {
        std::cout << "MOO!";
    }
    int m_a;
};

template <typename T>
class otherClass
{
public:
    otherClass(sampClass* doMoo)
    {
        doMoo->moo();
    }
};


int main()
{
    sampClass a(5);
    a.potato<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Above `otherClass` add `class otherClass;` and do not #include the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as adding a forward declaration:

```
#include <iostream>

//
// forward declare otherClass here
//
template <typename T>
class otherClass;

class sampClass
{
public:
    template <typename Z>
    otherClass<Z> potato()
    {
        return otherClass<Z>(this);

    }
    sampClass(int a)
    {
        m_a = a;
    }
    void moo()
    {
        std::cout << "MOO!";
    }
    int m_a;
};

template <typename T>
class otherClass
{
public:
    otherClass(sampClass* doMoo)
    {
        doMoo->moo();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you - works just as well with templated classes as regular ones. And you don't have to outline the method.